# Java - paintComponents on a JPanel not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, paintcomponent

I created a class that extends a `JFrame` and added a `JPanel` inside it, but the `paintComponents()` method doesn't draw anything on the `JPanel`. Heres the code for the `paintComponents()`, I chose to use double image buffering.

```
  public void paintComponents(Graphics graphics) {
     panel.paintComponents(graphics);

      bufferedImage = createImage(sizeX, sizeY);
      Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) bufferedImage.getGraphics();


      for (ImageData myImage : imageData) {
        g.drawImage(myImage.getImage(), myImage.getX(), myImage.getY(), null);
    }

    graphics.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, null);
  }
```

Is there anything wrong with this? Btw, I tried `paint()` and it worked but I dont think it's the proper way to do this.

Thanks for your time. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not extend a top level component such as a `JFrame`.  Instead keep an instance of a frame, and add a panel to that.  All custom painting or addition of components is done in the panel.

When doing custom painting in a panel, do it in the  `paintComponent` method (**not** `paintComponents` do not override that).

### Other tips

- Remember to call `super.paintComponent(g);`.  This is important to ensure that borders and padding etc. are accounted for.
- Swap `null` for `this`.  Every `JComponent` is an `ImageObserver`.

Comment: As I said, I extended the JFrame class so I cant do super.paintComponent

Comment: Also paintComponent does not exist, only paintComponents does

Comment: I have to, it's for the KeyListener, panel.addKeyListener(this);

Comment: @Ewen and Andrew suggested extending from a JPanel instead

Comment: @MadProgrammer The answer became significantly edited as the basis of 'frame' became more clear.  I had presumed a panel based on the title *"..paintComponents on a JPanel not working"*.  To be honest, I read no further, beyond confirming from the code snippet that the method name had an `s` - I offered my first answer 'remove the `s`'.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

please note that JFrame is NOT a JComponent! In fact, the `paintComponents(Graphics)` method is NEVER called. A fix would be subclassing JPanel and adding your subclassed panel to the frame as the content pane. In the panel override the `paintComponents(Graphics)` method.

Comment: How do I override paintComponents()?

Comment: you need to override the paint method or the better alternative would be using a jpanel and override its paintComponent method with all the stuff you are now doing in your extended jframe.

Comment: "..in the panel override the paintComponent(Graphics)" should be